# Sequelize: InstanceMethods aren't working if called before .save()

Tags: sequelize.js

I've been trying to explain this for a while.

I have a sequelize model like so:

```
return sequelize
    .define('Post', 
    {
        title: {type : DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: false},
        subtitle: {type : DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true},
        body: {type : DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
        status: {type : DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, defaultValue: "draft"},
        slug: {type : DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true, defaultValue: "slug"},

        created_at: {type : DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: false, defaultValue: new Date()},
        updated_at: {type : DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: false, defaultValue: new Date()},
        published_at: {type : DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: true, defaultValue: null}
    },  {
        associate: function(models){
            models.Post.hasMany(models.Tag);
            models.Post.hasMany(models.Category);
        },
        instanceMethods: {
            generateSlug: function(link){
                this.slug = _s.slugify(link);
                console.log('New Slug: '+this.slug);
                return;
            },
                  }
```

And I create a new post in the following method:

```
'createPost': function(req, res, next){ 

        db.Post.build({
            title:          req.body.post.title,
            subtitle:       req.body.post.subtitle,
            body:           req.body.post.body,
        }).generateSlug(req.body.post.title).save()
        .success(function(post){
            console.log('Successfully created post: '+post.title);
            res.json({post: post});
        }).failure(function(err){
            console.log('Error in creating post');
            res.send(404);
        });
},
```

This doesn't work and the call to save() doens't work, although the code does flow into generateSlug, the call to this.slug results in the default value, not the title slugified.

If I change it so that the generateSlug instanceMethod is called after the model is saved, it works perfectly:

```
db.Post.build({
            title:          req.body.post.title,
            subtitle:       req.body.post.subtitle,
            body:           req.body.post.body,
        }).save()
        .success(function(post){
                            post.generateSlug(post.title);
            console.log('Successfully created post: '+post.title);
            res.json({post: post});
        }).failure(function(err){...
```

Can someone help explain how this works? It's different than the docs which suggest the first attempt is correct db.build({}).instanceMethod().save(). Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Your generateSlug method should `return this` so you have something to call save on

Comment: Thanks Jan, that was it.